# Tableau TWBX file issue

Tags: tableau-api

I'm confused about 2 questions here :

1. Can I embed a tableau worksheet hosted on Tableau Public in tableau dashboard(using tableau desktop) using web container component of the dashboard ?
2. When i save a tableau workbook with live connection connected to say oracle db and save the file as twbx file, does the twbx file still contain the entire data source(schema used  in this case) in the twbx file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should be able to since it will be a url. however, if your goal is to just share the report you publish, then just share the url with the users.
2. the twbx file will only have the metadata for the connection, essentially a connection string, and the structure of the views/tables you are querying.. it won't have a full blueprint of the database, nor should it.

Comment: im still not sure about this. I think whatever table you are using it will contain the entire data stored in columnar format in a compressed manner. so if 10 milllion records contituent to 1gb data in oracle, twbx file will compress it and its size would be around 300 mb

Comment: your question was about tableau public, which means the workbook would be posted to a tableau server.. and you also mention that the connection is a live connection. those 2 factors dont add up to a file size you are mentioning. even if you dont do a live connection, you can save it as an extract, but that is saved as a separate file (tde extension). what you maybe doing is creatin a standalone file meant to be share with folks that have tableau reader.. if that is what you are doing, reconsider your approach since that is in conflict with a live connection

Comment: Gungor,with respect to ur reply "the twbx file will only have the metadata for the connection, essentially a connection string, and the structure of the views/tables you are querying.. it won't have a full blueprint of the database, nor should it."


What I feel is it still stores all the data in compressed format and not just the structural information

Comment: I have seen that the twbx file is no other thing that a twb.zip file.... eventough you change the filename of twbx to twb.zip and you can open it and see only the twb file inside (asuming a live connection) .......tdsx file is diferent.... (data source)....